# Nuget package restore error in build definition

Tags: tfs, nuget

I'm getting this error when building a project​ using Visual Studio online service build:

> Error:
>
> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ....\Attempt17\.nuget\NuGet.targets.

It is giving that `nuget.target` file is missing but it is already present in `.nuget` folder.

Any help?

Comment: @Dipali: please use only code ticks `for` words that are `code`, and not `for` anything else concerning software `or` code. Also, please do not randomly bold phrases (as you did in some of your other edits). They do **not** "improve formatting".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a "Nuget Package Restore" task to your build before you run your compilation. You no longer need a ".nuget" folder.

Comment: Ref: https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/package-restore#migrating-to-automatic-restore

Comment: Thanks will try this.

Comment: @neha Have you tried the "Nuget Package Restore" task? How's the result?

Comment: I tried it and issue got resolved. Thanks and sorry for late reply.

Comment: @neha can you share how you exactly achieved this? I'm on the same page here

Answer (score 0):

I had a different cause, in VSTS/Azure DevOps using "Use Nuget" first then "NuGet restore" second, on Hosted agent...the restore was throwing this error. Error began showing sometime around Feb 1, 2019.

I had to change this...

```
Path to solution, packages.config, or project.json: **/*.sln
```

to this...

```
Path to solution, packages.config, or project.json: **\{YOUR_SOLUTION_NAME}.sln
```

And the error went away.

Hope this helps!